# Unable to set the custom text color of Actionbar Tabs

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, customization

I am using android studio V0.82
I am trying to modify the text color of the tabs when pressed but it isn't happening as it was expected to be.
Below are my style.xml and drawable/tabtextcolor codes.
If anyone could tell what is the problem here.

style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle.Transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@color/black</item>

    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@color/black</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle.Transparent" parent="@android:Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@null</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle.Transparent.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle.Transparent.TitleTextStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="@android:Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tabcolor</item>
</style>>
```

drawable/tabtextstyle.xml

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />
```

Comment: i will recommend you to use this tool http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/   it generates style files for you keep them in you drawable folders thats it .

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="TabTextStyle"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

put this in your styles.xml in the regular values folder 
and put this

```
<item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
```

in both your styles xml files in the like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<!-- <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle.Transparent</item>
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="actionBarDivider">@color/black</item>
<item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
<item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@color/black</item>
```